# Combining 3 querys on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with both, Products and Sevices. And I store the *products brands*, *product names* and *services names* on separate tables.

I get the list of Services with this Query:

```
SELECT maeinvs.idInv, CONCAT(services.Service, " ", maeinvs.Detail) AS Name
FROM maeinvs
INNER JOIN services
ON services.idService = maeinvs.idService
```

And the list of Products with this one:

```
SELECT maeinvs.idInv, CONCAT(brands.Brand, " ", products.Product, " ", maeinvs.Detail) AS Name
FROM maeinvs
INNER JOIN products
ON products.idProduct = maeinvs.idProduct
INNER JOIN brands
ON brands.idBrand = maeinvs.idBrand
```

I need to get a Query like this, but instead of the *idInv* field I need the actual *Name* of the Product or Service. Any ideas?

```
SELECT idInv, Desc, Qnty, Price
FROM invoicedetails
WHERE idInvoice = $id
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think for somebody to answer this, you might have to give the create table scripts for all the tables involved. 

From the look of data you have seen so far, it looks like a straightforward join between multiple tables. Are you sure you have tried your hand at join queries and they aren't working? It might be better if you try firing queries, check their results, and report what is working and not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how to do it on a single query (I just know the basics; an Alias?) but solved it doing a *VIEW* and then a *JOIN* with my *invoicedetails* table.

VIEW:

```
SELECT maeinvs.idInv, CONCAT(services.Service, " ", maeinvs.Detail) AS Name
FROM maeinvs
INNER JOIN services
ON services.idService = maeinvs.idService
UNION
SELECT maeinvs.idInv, CONCAT(brands.Brand, " ", products.Product, " ", maeinvs.Detail) AS Name
FROM maeinvs
INNER JOIN products
ON products.idProduct = maeinvs.idProduct
INNER JOIN brands
ON brands.idBrand = maeinvs.idBrand
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT viewnames.Name, invoicedetails.Desc, invoicedetails.Qnty, invoicedetails.Price
FROM invoicedetails
INNER JOIN viewnames ON viewnames.idInv = invoicedetails.idInv
WHERE invoicedetails = $id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT maeinvs.idInv, CONCAT(services.Service, " ", maeinvs.Detail) AS Name,
"" AS Desc, 0 AS Qnty, 0 AS Price
FROM maeinvs
INNER JOIN services
ON services.idService = maeinvs.idService
UNION
SELECT maeinvs.idInv, CONCAT(brands.Brand, " ", products.Product, " ", maeinvs.Detail) AS Name,
"" AS Desc, 0 AS Qnty, 0 AS Price
FROM maeinvs
INNER JOIN products
ON products.idProduct = maeinvs.idProduct
INNER JOIN brands
ON brands.idBrand = maeinvs.idBrand
UNION
SELECT idInv, 
"" AS Name,
Desc, Qnty, Price
FROM invoicedetails
WHERE idInvoice = $id
```

I've written what I've changed on next line
As the columns match each other, UNION will work.

Comment: It gives me all the inventory, I needed a UNION and then a JOIN to get only the invoice details. Anyway, thanks for your answer, it help me to find a solution.